# AWS Cognito Node.JS User Authentication returns unknown problem

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito with Node.JS.

I'm successfully registering and verifying users, but the Authentication is returning "unknown error, the response body from fetch is undefined."

I'm using node-fetch module along with amazon-cognito-identity-js (set as var AWSCognito on code below). User is not in a state of requiring password change and verified.

Have others experienced this and how did you resolve the issue?
Appreciate any guidance in advance....

Here's my code, my complete module is on npm as iditawsutils :

```
exports.authCognitoUser = function(theUserPoolID, theClientID, userName, userPassword) {

    var authenticationData = {
        Username : userName,
        Password : userPassword
    };

    var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

    var poolData = { UserPoolId : theUserPoolID,
        ClientId : theClientID
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

    var userData = {
        Username : userName,
        Pool : userPool
    };

    console.log('authentication details: ',authenticationDetails);

    var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
            console.log('id token + ' + result.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
            console.log('refresh token + ' + result.getRefreshToken().getToken());
            return result;
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            console.log(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
            return err;
        },

    });

}
```

//from the console log:

```
authentication details:  AuthenticationDetails {
  validationData: {},
  authParameters: {},
  username: 'thesmarterstuff',
  password: 'passW0rd!’ }
```

Unknown error, the response body from fetch is: undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your onFailure block to find more details about the error.

```
onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log(new Error().stack);
        console.log(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
    },
```

If you find the error occurring in your fetch line in Client.js, then this could be because currently NodeJS SDK, and most other SDKs do not support the default USER_SRP_AUTH.

You could check by adding a console.log in the Client.js

```
console.log(this.endpoint);
console.log(options);
```

Login to your AWS account, and make sure you have checked the option - Enable username-password (non-SRP) flow for app-based authentication (USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)

Then, in your code update it with the following setting.

```
cognitoUser.setAuthenticationFlowType('USER_PASSWORD_AUTH');
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out! I appreciate it. I had the option set but didn't have the cognitoUser.setAuthenticationFlowType('USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'); line in my code...now getting the access token and refresh token.   Thanks!  Steve